# Laravel, Search by month, but I can't find anything

Tags: laravel, search

I'm doing a search a month, but I can't find anything. Start is a column of type date, 2020-07-23.

Controller:

```
public function cityName(Request $request, City $city)
{
    $month = $request->month;
    $status = $request->status;

    if (!empty($month)) {
       $chamado = Chamados::where('cite_id', $city->id)
                ->whereMonth('start', $month)
                ->when($status, function ($query, $status) {
                    return $query->where('status', $status);
       })->get();
                
    } else {
        $chamado = Chamados::where('cite_id', $city->id)->get();            
    }

    $total = Chamados::where('cite_id', $city->id)->value(DB::raw('SUM(total)'));

    return view('admin.reports.city.city_name', compact('city', 'chamado', 'total', 'month'));
}
```

My form:

```
<form class="form-inline mb-3" action="{{ route('dashboard.report.city.name', $city->id) }}" id="formSearch" method="GET">
<input type="month" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-md-2" name="month" id="month" value="{{ isset($month) ? $month : '' }}">

<button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2 mb-2">
    <i class="fad fa-filter"></i> Filter
</button>
</form>
```

without search
[image]

with search
[image]

Comment: please read the documentation futher you can search date by month by using ->whereMonth()

Comment: I already read, I'm not wanting the date, but the month. Fixed the code, it was already whereMonth

Comment: then whats your problem ?

Comment: I added images to better explain.

Comment: can you see your url please, month=2020-07, its not only by month

Comment: Yes, I typed in the URL only the month and it worked, so I will have to select only the months. I am very grateful for your help, I will try to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

The [whereMonth()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific month of a year:

```
$chamado = Chamados::whereMonth('start', $month)
```